# RichEmbed discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hey sorry for my bad English I'm French

I am trying to create a RichEmbed constructor for my poll discord.js bot. I expected my code to send a RichEmbed but when I type the command nothing happens, I just get this error message:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined`

Here's my code:

```js
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  function extractAllText(str){
    const re = /"(.*?)"/g;
    const result = [];
    let current;
    while (current = re.exec(str)) {
      result.push(current.pop());
    }
    return result.length > 0
      ? result
      : [str];
  }

  result = extractAllText(message.content)

  //Here
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle(result[0])
    .setAuthor(message.author)
    .setDescription('Sondage')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Vous pouvez voter en cliquant sur les réactions ci-dessous.');

  for (let i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
    embed.addField(i, result[i])
  }

  message.channel.send(embed);

};
```

I tried to replace MessageEmbed() with RichEmbed(), but I get another error that says:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

I also tried to use an embed object, but I couldn't find a way to use a for loop in that kind of embed.

At the top of my file, I tried to write:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true})
```

but it still doesn't work

Thank you for reading this, have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by updating discord.js to version 12 by typing `yarn add discord.js` again from powershell (I think it should be `npm install discord.js` for npm).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add on the top of your module file :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
```

or, you could try to modify this in your `app.js/index.js` :

```
commandFile.run(bot, message, args)
```

with :

```
commandFile.run(Client, bot, message, args)
```

EDIT :

Modify :

```
let sEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
```

With :

```
let sEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I still have ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined```

Comment: modify 'client' by 'bot' !

Comment: ```js
command.run(Client, bot, message, args);
```
Is this good? I still have the same error

Comment: Here is the code of my command file: https://pastebin.com/JewHNRh3

Comment: I tried to modify MessageEmbed() with RichEmbed() but now it says 
`(node:33) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

Comment: Try to catch the error ! Try maybe this before : 
`let sEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed().setTitle('My title').setDescription('Sondage');
 
return message.channel.send({sEmbed});`

Comment: I wrote this: `message.channel.send({sEmbed}).catch(err => console.log(err));`
And I got this log: https://pastebin.com/p5CxPRmN

Comment: Are you sure your embed message isn't empty ? Did you try with a classic message or with my example ?

Comment: I tried to send a regular message and it worked but when I do:
`let sEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()`
`.setTitle('My title')`
`.setDescription('Sondage');`
It still says cannot send empty message